# How to use api_gateway_base_path_mapping with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform

I'm trying to setup a custom domain name for an api in api gateway on aws. I have setup the api fine using terraform. However when I try to setup the custom domain it fails with the following error.

Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

- module.BillingMetrics.aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping.billing: 1 error(s) occurred:
- aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping.billing: Error creating Gateway base path mapping: Error creating Gateway base path mapping: BadRequestException: Invalid REST API identifier specified
      status code: 400, request id: b14bbd4c-5823-11e7-a4ea-93525a34b321

I can see in the terraform log that it does get the correct api_id. But I don't understand why it's saying the rest api identifier is invalid.

Below is an excerpt of my terraform file showing how I'm configuring the api_gateway_base_path_mapping.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "views_resource" {
  provider = "aws.regional"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.billing_api.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.billing_api.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "views"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "views-get" {
  provider = "aws.regional"
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.billing_api.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.views_resource.id}"
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "views_200" {
  provider = "aws.regional"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.billing_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.views_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.views-get.http_method}"
  status_code = "200"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "views-integration" {
  provider = "aws.regional"
  rest_api_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.billing_api.id}"
  resource_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.views_resource.id}"
  http_method             = "${aws_api_gateway_method.views-get.http_method}"
  type                    = "AWS"
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:function:${aws_lambda_function.get_views.function_name}/invocations"
  credentials             = "${var.metrics_role_arn}"
  http_method             = "${aws_api_gateway_method.views-get.http_method}"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "Views_Get_IntegrationResponse" {
  provider = "aws.regional"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.billing_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.views_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.views-get.http_method}"
  status_code = "${aws_api_gateway_method_response.views_200.status_code}"
 }

/* Deploy api */
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "metric_deploy" {
  provider = "aws.regional"
  depends_on  = ["aws_api_gateway_integration.metrics-integration", "aws_api_gateway_integration.hours-integration"]
  stage_name  = "beta"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.billing_api.id}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "billing" {
  domain_name       = "billing.example.com"
  certificate_arn   = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:6--:certificate/5--"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping" "billing" {
  api_id      = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.billing_api.id}"
  stage_name  = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.metric_deploy.stage_name}"
  domain_name = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.billing.domain_name}"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "billing" {
  zone_id = "Z-------"

  name = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.billing.domain_name}"
  type = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.billing.cloudfront_domain_name}"
    zone_id                = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.billing.cloudfront_zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

Are there any more elements that needed to be configured to have the base_path_mapping apply correctly? Any other hints what I might be doing wrong?

I should also mention I'm on terraform 0.9.7.

Comment: Dependency ordering? The API/Stage must exist prior to adding the base path mapping. I haven't used Terraform so I'm not sure if that is already handled. Everything else looks correct.

Comment: Did you tried adding `depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_rest_api.billing_api"]` in aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping resource? It seems like a dependency problem

Comment: I did try that but no joy. As far as I can tell it seems to be some issue on the aws side as creating the custom domain name for ACM certificates can take 40 minutes. And trying from the aws cli does not seem to work either. Only succeeded when I did it manually from the aws console.